# VB.NET application with SQL Server Express

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am developing simple application using VB.NET and SQL Server Express.

The application runs well and has full functionality on the PC I developed (that has both SQL Server and vb.net installed). The problem is, when I try to install another computer I get an error:

> Cannot open database "DatabaseName" Requested by the login. Login failed.
>   Login failed for the user "UserNameOfTheComputer"

Please see the images:

[Error][1]

And please advice what is the best way that customer can use offline application developed in VB.NET

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the user have SQL Server Express installed?  What is your connection string?

Comment: Verify the installation, then verify that you actually have created the database, and then user credentials - because the error message points to the credentials being the problem.

Comment: you might require to use the computer name in conjuction with the user name in format : pcname\username

Comment: The problem here is not about connectivity between the application and sql server. Otherwise the error that you will be getting is something like this: *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.*. You have to check if (1) the server was configure to use `SQL Authentication Login`, (2) or the user has keyed in the correct password, (3) or the username used to login exists on the server, (4) or the username is allowed to access that database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using localhost server or actually pointing to network server?

If you are pointing to network server, add the PC-name or IP of the server before the SQL server name. e.g : 192.168.1.200/SQLSERVER instead of localhost/SQLSERVER

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing in your development machine you are using local SQL server (SQL server and Visual Studio are on the same machine), so to use this in a client PC you need to have your client PC installed with SQL Server and Set Your .exe.config connection string to your client PC Sql Server.for and offline probably you could try a built in database from the Visual Studio it self.